# SQL Joining where data values may be Anglicized

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, character, alphabet

I want to figure out how to join on a field when a user may have entered an English spelling of a word because of the keys available.  This would be like replacing Küss with Kuss, François with Francois, José with Jose.

I've seen the terms "collation" and "regex" in several posts.  I tried

```
    SELECT Company collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI, Company
    FROM tblCompany
```

but my umlaut was still there, so that wouldn't join on where the umlaut wasn't used.

Any help to set me on a path would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Leading practice is to join on an integer key not on a string.  Now you know why.

Comment: To be sure! But if you don't have a unique identifier available, you have to work with what is at hand.  In this particular case, it's providing international users to look themselves up in a system using a standard American keyboard to find the row that would provide that very number if present.

Answer (score 1):

Try a SOUNDEX function. It compares words that are spelled differently but sound simmilar :

```
Select * from users where SOUNDEX(name) = SOUNDEX('José')
```

would give you lines for Jose and José